# Change default g++ architecture on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos

With Mac OS X 10.6 Apple changed the default target of g++ so it produces 64-bit rather than 32-bit code. I know I can specify "-arch i386" on the command line but is there any way to *globally* change the default architecture by means of an environment variable or similar? (I keep getting linking errors because I'm having real problems finding **all** the places I need to specify the architecture on the project I'm porting.)

Comment: cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch" - I think you meant -m32, did you not?

Comment: @user502515: `-arch` is an Apple-specific GCC option.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. Depending on the configuration & build system you’re using, setting the `CXXFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, and `LDFLAGS` environmental variables to include `-arch i386` can help. However, some configuration & build system are tricky and it might not be sufficient to set those variables.

Another option is to provide a `g++` (and friends as needed) bash script in a `PATH` location that precedes `/usr/bin` and invokes the actual command with `-arch i386` along with the command-line arguments passed to the script.

An alternative to the solution described in the previous paragraph is to use `arch(1)` in one of its various forms. For instance, the shell script described above could invoke `arch -i386 /usr/bin/g++`. You can also set the `ARCHPREFERENCE` environmental variable to something like `g++:/usr/bin/g++:i386,x86_64` and invoke `arch /usr/bin/g++`. However, note that you must use `arch` to invoke `/usr/bin/g++`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

You could set your path so that it searches your private bin directory first.
In this bin directory place a g++ script that explicitly invokes the correct g++ compiler will the appropriate flags.

#### Option 2

Set a g++ alias. This will then be used in preference to a command. Set the alias to run the command with the appropriate flags.

Note: Both of these assume you are building from the command line as XCode probably explicitly executes the g++ binary.

Comment: One must be careful when using aliases since they aren’t inherited by subshells.