# OpenImageDenoise - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when using precompiled header in C++

Tags: c++, macos, raytracing

I am trying to use the odin library (https://github.com/OpenImageDenoise/oidn/) within my project, but I am unable to get it to link successfully. When I include the library and use the example code from the documentation, my IDE does not flag any errors. However upon trying to compile it with cmake I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_oidnCommitDevice", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
  "_oidnCommitFilter", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
  "_oidnExecuteFilter", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
  "_oidnGetDeviceError", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
  "_oidnNewDevice", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_oidnNewFilter", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
  "_oidnReleaseDevice", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_oidnReleaseFilter", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
  "_oidnSetSharedFilterImage", referenced from:
      data_denoise(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure if I need to link the library within the cmake file, since there is nothing related to that in the documentation.

Comment: Undefined reference always means your code references functions that aren't in your program - so you need to link to the library.

Comment: did you install all the dependencies? for instance in the github page they said "Cloning without Git LFS will seemingly succeed but actually some of the files will be invalid and thus compilation will fail."

Comment: @ma1169 The dependencies are used for building from source. I installed odin from a precompiled release.

Comment: the reason for the error  is that the target platform mismatch, i downloaded the 64 bit and tried to compile it on 32 bit, i got the same error you have.

Comment: @ma1169 I use a 64 bit system, so that might not be the problem. However, I am not sure if cmake compiles my file as 64 bit. Do you think that might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Not what I meant, they have [multiple binaries](https://github.com/OpenImageDenoise/oidn/releases) each for targeted platform, I downloaded the 64bit, because i am windows user ,it seems you are using x86_64,so you are either mac or Linux user so try to select a matching architecture in your sample project settings

Comment: @ma1169 I use a mac, so I downloaded the macos version, which did not work. There is only one option for mac so I selected that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593151/change-default-g-architecture-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @ma1169 I have tried building using 32 bit but I was unable to, with the warning "The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)". I believe this means that macos no longer supports building from 32 bit

Comment: @ma1169 sorry, didn't work. I got the same error.

Comment: how about -lstdc++ -x with -arch x86_64

Comment: @ma1169 no dice.

Comment: Then I have no clue!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I just needed to link the dylib to cmake.