# SDL2 M1 Mac - The linked and embedded framework 'SDL2_image.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64

Tags: c++, sdl

Just starting out using SDL2 on an **M1 Mac**. Everything has been working well so far until I've tried to use the *SDL image library*.

When I reference somthing from the libary on this line

```cpp
SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load("assets/test.png");
```

It causes the program not to compile, with the error:

```
g++ src/main.cpp -o main -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_IMG_LoadTexture", referenced from:
      Game::Game(char const*, int, int, int, int, bool) in main-5b0e78.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [game] Error 1
```

I'm assuming the library is loading correctly as IntelliSense can follow the Method back to the header file, and there no errors with the `#include <SDL2_image/SDL_image.h>`

Do I need to include this library in the g++ as well? and if so, what's the format to link multiple frameworks?

EDIT :

tried recreating the project in Xcode instead of Visual Studio Code. When I try to run the project I get a more specific error:

```
The linked and embedded framework 'SDL2_image.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64.
```

How would I fix this error. I can find a version of the library that includes arm64. Am I to assume this library has not been configured to work with Arm-based Apple Silicon Macs?

Answer (score 1):

Adding "arm64" to Project -> Build Settings -> Excluded Architecture fixed the issue for me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer one of your questions, you do need to include it in the g++. You can just do `-framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image` and that should supposedly work.

It didn't seem like the SDL2 framework included SDL_Image, so [I got it separately](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) and put it in "Library/Frameworks"

But I'm having the same issue you are having. I have a Silicon Mac and I'm getting the same exact error message, which makes me think that SDL_image doesn't support arm64 processors yet. But I could be wrong, hopefully I am wrong and there is some sort of fix.

Comment: I got it to work by changing the build target to Intel (rosetta) and adding “arm64” to excluded architectures

Comment: Ah well I'm not using an IDE, just doing this in a text editor. Maybe theres some sort of g++ flag for this?

Comment: Someone’s asked that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593151/change-default-g-architecture-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Hmm adding `-arch x86_64` is causing macos to prevent it from opening because it can't "check it for malicious software." I think my best bet would be to just move development over to my laptop running linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-lSDL2_image` into your build command.